# How to dismiss presentmodelviewController with other presentmodelviewController

Tags: iphone

I have a presentModelViewControler (A) which pops up when there is no network connectivity. Now i have a another presentModelViewController (B) which shows calendar.

Difficulty is when B is active i.e. shows calendar view then if internet goes down then A doesnot get active.

I want when B is active if A starts i.e. internet goes down, then it release B and pop up A.

```
        CalendarTestViewController *clau=[[CalendarTestViewController alloc]init];



        if (clau.modalViewController==TRUE) {


            [clau dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2f];


        }




        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:inter animated:YES];//network view controller

        [inter release];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it in stages.

1. dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on your calendar view.
2. wait until the view.modalViewController becomes nil
3. present network connectivity controller.

The second step is the one that isn't obvious.

The way I did this is in my method that presents my equivalent of the network connectivity. I have a loop first watching the modalViewController property.

Something like:

```
-(void)presentNetworkModal
{
     while (myVC.modalViewController) 
     {
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.2f];
     }
     [myVC presentModalViewController:myNetworkNotifier animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: My A and B model view controllers are in different classes. So it will work with them?

Comment: and step 3. present network connectivity controller means presenting model view controller of network??

Comment: Don't need to wait if you set animated to NO in dismiss (you can set to YES in present)

Comment: Diff classes is fine, and yes re: step 3.

Comment: Yes i have done this but calendar model view controller is not resigning and network view controller is not pop up. im writting my code in my question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you show an alert dialog when there's no network activity? Using a modal view controller for that might not be the best idea.

Comment: No I want to show model view controller coz i want user wont do anything when there is no internet and simply exit app.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use UIAlertView for no available network. so on click on Ok you can exit the app. ModalViewController is not a good idea, but if you really want some thing like that then you can use [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I hope you UIActionSheet would be the great idea, if not let me know.

Comment: Actually i dont wnt to exit application when network is not available. i want to give user freedom. if they want to wait or network comes quickly then they can start from the same place. So i dont want alert

Comment: Please have a look on updated question ihave shown my code.but not working

Comment: Your code does not describe more. and **how you test it the internet connection is up/down?** if is up then hide the B but this is really a nasty way because its a bad idea to give more action on a single page other wise never hide the status bar(it show about n/w status) of your view controller. so the user can see on status bar itself whether my device wifi is on/off.

Comment: No my moto is not to tell user if his wifi is on or not. my motive of doing this is to stop user to do anything i just want him to wait until connection comes up or he/she can just exit app.That is why not using alert or something else